# POO and Interface (in C#)

Tags: c#, oop, interface, dependency-injection

I need to understand Interface :

I have this structure :

```
Core (contain Interface)
BLL (Contain object who implement interface 
DAL (Contain Data access)
IHM (Call BLL object)
```

For example, i have an Interface Core.IVehicle who describe a basic vehicle like :

```
Color
Speed
```

And a one method :

```
LoadVehicle(int id) //return a iVehicule with speed and color
```

In my BLL, I have an object "BLL.Car" who implement "Core.IVehicle".
So, i will have a LoadVehicle method and access to DALfor get basics informations

But DAL need to return an object "BLL.Car" implemented. But i can't make a reference to BLL because of Circular Dependencies.

What i've miss? How my DAL can return an object "BLL.Car" implemented?

Comment: poco .. plain old clr objects

Comment: I think you mean OOP Object Oriented Programming

Comment: What do you mean your DAL should return BLL.Car Implemented? Do you mean your DAL should return a BLL object that has all it;s attributes filled from the database?

Comment: Read this question it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042114/need-help-understanding-interfaces

Comment: @FaddishWorm in italian oop Object Orientented Programming -> POO Programmazione Orientata agli Oggetti. I guess in france is something similar

Comment: POO is OOP in french. Thanks for replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But DAL need to return an object "BLL.Car" implemented.

This is probably where the confusion lies.

Your DAL **should not** return the BLL version of `Car`, the DAL should have it's own version of `Car` aka *entity* / *DAO* (data access object). The BLL should query the DAL for the car "entity" (whether it be returned as a DTO or an `IVehicle`) and construct it's own representation of `Car` aka Domain Model.

So to summarise you should have 2 (or 3 if you want a view model as well) versions of `Car` i.e.

**Entity/DAO (DAL)**

```
public class Car : IVehicle
{
}
...
public class CarRepository
{
    ...
    public IVehicle LoadVehicle(int id)
    {
        var entity = // query DB for instance of DAL.Car
        return entity;
    }
}
```

**Domain Model (BLL)**

```
public class Car : IVehicle
{
}
...
public class CarService
{
    public IVehicle FindCarById(int id)
    {
        var repo = new DAL.CarRepository(...);
        var carEntity = repo.LoadVehicle(id); // returns DAL.Car instance 
        return new BLL.Car // we turn DAL.Car into our DLL.Car
        {
            Color = carEntity.Color,
            Speed = carEntity.Speed
        };
    }
}
```

**IHM (View)**

```
public class Controller
{
    public void ViewCarDetails(int id)
    {
        var carService = new BLL.CarService();
        var car = carService.FindCarById(id);
        // populate UI with `car` properties
    }
}
```

Because `IVehicle` is in the Core DLL it can be shared across all your layers, so you don't need to worry about circular references, and it gives you a consistent return type.

Comment: But is [all this layering worth the mapping](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/02/09/IsLayeringWorththeMapping/)?

Comment: @Steven if you want to achieve a pure layered architecture, then yes it is. Libraries like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) make this mundane task pretty simple. I understand the point Mark is trying to make (I have read that article before) however, for me, it's still good practise to keep your domain independent from the UI & DAL because, let's face it, applications evolve and no matter how sure you are that things won't change - no-one can predict the future. So the question really becomes is it worth the effort to separate your layers now vs. having to refactor later?